# Get the nth day of last full week in any given month (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to get the Wednesday of the last full week in April each year. Output example: April 24, 2019, April 22, 2020, April 28, 2021, April 27, 2022, etc.

How can I identify the last full week in any given month?

```
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
var d = new Date(y, 3, 0);
var NumWks = Math.floor(d.getDate() - 1 / 7) + 1;
```

I've only managed to get the number of weeks in April (in above example) (result: 5) but the 5th week is not a complete week so I need the 4th week. I need some kind of test to check if the last week is a full week, if not, use the week before?

```
var nth = //this is what I need to figure out, the last full week in April.
```

Once I've managed to get the nth of the full week, i can use the rest of the formula

```
var Wed = 3;
var FirstWedofApril = new Date(y, 3, 1 + (Wed - new Date(y, 3, 1).getDay() + 7) % 7);
var LastWedOfFullWeek = new Date(FirstWedofApril.getFullYear(), FirstWedofApril.getMonth(), FirstWedofApril.getDate() + (nth - 1) * 7);
```

I got the above formula from [Date Hacks](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/6322-date-hacks-doing-javascript-date-calculations.html)

**EDIT FINAL CODE**
The for loop is just to test the next 10 years.

```
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();


for (i = 0, i < 10; i++) {
var yr = y + i;
var apr = 3;
var wed = 3;

//Get first Wednesday in April
var FirstWed = new Date(yr, apr, 1 + (wed - new Date(yr, apr, 1).getDay() + 7) % 7);


//Get Number of weeks in April    
var d = new Date(yr, apr, 0);
var NumWks = Math.floor((d.getDate() - 1) / 7) + 1;

//Get Last Date in April
var lastDateApr = new Date(yr, apr + 1, 1);
    lastDateApr.setDate(lastDateApr.getDate() -1 );

//Get Last Date in April - Day of Week
var dow = lastDateApr.getDay();

//Get Wednesday of last full week in April
if (dow == 7) {
    var lastWed = new Date(FirstWed.getFullYear(), FirstWed.getMonth(), FirstWed.getDate() + (NumWks - 1) * 7);
} else {
    var lastFullWk = NumWks - 1;
    var lastWed = new Date(FirstWed.getFullYear(), FirstWed.getMonth(), FirstWed.getDate() + (lastFullWk - 1) * 7);
}

text = text + yr + ": " + lastWed + '<br>';
}
document.getElementById("WedAprLastFW").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Below are the output:

- 2019: Wed Apr 24 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2020: Wed Apr 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2021: Wed Apr 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2022: Wed Apr 27 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2023: Wed Apr 26 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2024: Wed Apr 24 2024 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2025: Wed Apr 23 2025 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2026: Wed Apr 22 2026 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2027: Wed Apr 28 2027 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
- 2028: Wed Apr 26 2028 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get the last day of month, check what day it is, and substract days depending on the weekday

on sunday -3
on monday -4
on tuesday  -5
on wednesday -6
on thursday -7
on friday -8
on saturday -9

then you get the last thursday in a full week in the month

edit : also to check if your week is a full week is when the last day is a sunday or saturday, depending on locale

edit2: to get the last day of the month you get the first day of the month after (thats easy because its the first) and substract a day

Comment: Thanks @Bacon. I got it to work. I updated my original post with the final code